# C# - Can not find S-1-5-4 (Interactive users group) sid

Tags: c#

I am adding interactive account sid to "Event Log Readers" group.

```
  var eventLogReadersSid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WinBuiltinEventLogReadersGroup, null);

  var interactiveUsersSid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.InteractiveSid, null);

  using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
  {
      using (var elreadersGroupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.Sid, eventLogReadersSid.Value))
      {
          using (var interactiveSidPrincipal = Principal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.Sid, interactiveUsersSid.Value))
          {
              if (!elreadersGroupPrincipal.Members.Contains(interactiveSidPrincipal))
              {
                  elreadersGroupPrincipal.Members.Add(interactiveSidPrincipal);
                  elreadersGroupPrincipal.Save();
                  DebugLog($"Users ({interactiveSidPrincipal.Name}) added to Event Log Readers ({elreadersGroupPrincipal.Name})");
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

This code works fine, but VERY slow (my machine is not in domain).
I tried PrincipalSearcher - its faster, but I *can not find* **Interactive users group** sid.

```
  var eventLogReadersSid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WinBuiltinEventLogReadersGroup, null);
  var interactiveUsersSid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.InteractiveSid, null);

  using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
  {
      PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = principalContext;

      GroupPrincipal grp = new GroupPrincipal(principalContext);
      PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher();
      grp.Name = "*";
      searcher.QueryFilter = grp;
      PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = searcher.FindAll();
      foreach (Principal u in results)
      {
          Debug.WriteLine($"::: {u.Name} :::");
      }
  }
```

I am not a professional programmer, so I need a help.
How can I find Interactive users group sid to add it to EventLog Reader group?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why do you think you need to add someone to the [INTERACTIVE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-special-identities-groups#interactive) group ?  (Microsoft says: "When a user accesses a specific resource on the computer to which they're currently logged on, the user is automatically added to the Interactive group" )

Comment: I need access to read Security Log journal. So I need to add a user to this group. I don't know, what user will need this access, so I just add all interactive users to the group EventLogReaders, so any currently log user can read events from this journal.

Answer (score 0):

I managed it partially, but the speed is increased greatly:

```
    var elrSid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WinBuiltinEventLogReadersGroup, null);
    var interactiveUsersSid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.InteractiveSid, null);

    using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
    {
        using (var queryFilter = new GroupPrincipal(principalContext))
        {
            PrincipalSearcher elrSearcher = new(queryFilter);
                using (var elrPrincipal = elrSearcher.FindAll().Cast<GroupPrincipal>()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Sid.Value.Equals(elrSid.Value)))
            {
                using (var interactiveSidPrincipal = Principal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.Sid, interactiveUsersSid.Value))
                {
                    if (elrPrincipal is not null && !elrPrincipal.Members.Contains(interactiveSidPrincipal))
                    {
                        elrPrincipal.Members.Add(interactiveSidPrincipal);
                        elrPrincipal.Save();
                        DebugLog($"Users ({interactiveSidPrincipal.Name}) added to Event Log Readers ({elrPrincipal.Name})");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```